# What is the Python equivalent of Javascript's `Date.prototype.toISOString`?

Tags: python, iso8601

In Javascript, `Date.prototype.toISOString` gives an ISO 8601 UTC datetime string:

```
new Date().toISOString()
// "2014-07-24T00:19:37.439Z"
```

Is there a Python function with behavior that matches Javascript's?

---

Attempts:

Python's `datetime.datetime.isoformat` is similar, but not quite the same:

```
datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
// '2014-07-24T00:19:37.439728'
```

Using `pytz` I can at least make UTC explicit:

```
pytz.utc.localize(datetime.now()).isoformat())
// '2014-07-24T00:19:37.439728+00:00'
```

Comment: No, Python doesn't have a builtin function that does what you want here, you have to write your own, or use something like [DateTime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime/4.0.1) which is absolutely and completely overkill for what you want to do. (scroll down to ISO8601 and HTML4 methods).  Really though, the two answers provided below are exactly what you want to do, just change the timezone.

Comment: ^ This should be an answer, +1

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
iso_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Comment: So, that works for the specific case of `datetime.now()`, but this approach won't work with a timezone-aware datetime, right?

Answer (score 5):

This did it for me, just using python's standard library:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def isoformat_js(dt: datetime):
    return (
        dt.astimezone(timezone.utc)
        .isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")
        .replace("+00:00", "Z")
    )



isoformat_js(datetime(2014, 7, 24, 0, 19, 37, 439000))
# => '2014-07-24T00:19:37.439Z'
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant of the answers imo.  FYI for future visitors who just want a snippet for toISOString for "now" (note requires `dateutil` 3rd party lib): 

`datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tzlocal()).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')`

Comment: I'm not a huuuuge fan of the string replacement (it works fine but feels gross). In my code I'm using `dt.astimezone(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds") + "Z"`, which ought to be equivalent

Answer (score 3):

I attempted to format the string to exactly how it is in the javascript output.

```
from datetime import datetime

def iso_format(dt):
    try:
        utc = dt + dt.utcoffset()
    except TypeError as e:
        utc = dt
    isostring = datetime.strftime(utc, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.{0}Z')
    return isostring.format(int(round(utc.microsecond/1000.0)))

print iso_format(datetime.now())
#"2014-07-24T00:19:37.439Z"
```

Comment: This, like the other answer, depends on the datetime not having timezone information attached to it. I'm looking for something more general.

Comment: To account for a timezone aware ```datetime``` object, the first statement in the function could be ````utc = dt + dt.utcoffset()```.  Then subsequent statements would operate on ```utc``` instead of ```dt```.

Comment: This solution gives me a literal `.{0}Z` in this string. To maintain compatability with Javascript's toISOString, shouldn't this output `.000Z` if python `datetime`s don't give millisecond precision?

Answer (score 3):

Using f-strings in Python 3.6+

```py
from datetime import datetime

f'{datetime.now():%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Used dateutil package from https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/
import datetime
import dateutil.tz

def iso_format(dt):
    try:
        utc_dt = dt.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc())
    except ValueError:
        utc_dt = dt
    ms = "{:.3f}".format(utc_dt.microsecond / 1000000.0)[2:5]
    return datetime.datetime.strftime(utc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.{0}Z'.format(ms))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a Python function with behavior that matches Javascript's?

Not in the standard library, but you could build your own.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is [ISO 8601 date format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)  itself allows for two things:

1. Use of either 'Z' or '+00:00' to represent UTC as used by javascript and python respectively
2. Number of digits in the decimal fraction of a second is not limited. So, python uses 6 (microsecond precision) and javascript uses 3 (millisecond precision)

So, both are correct and we need to handle the conversion with one or more of the tricks above. I use the following:

1. Python date object to javascript ISO format string:
   `pyDateObj = datetime.now() jsISOTimeStr = pyDateObj.astimezone(pytz.timezone("UTC")).isoformat()[:-9] + 'Z'`
2. Javascript date object to python ISO format string:
   In javascript:
   `const jsDateObj = new Date(); jsISOTimeStr = date.toISOString()`
   Later, in python:
   `pyDateObj = datetime.fromisoformat(jsISOTimeStr [:-1]+'000+00:00')`

Answer (score 0):

you may also use:

```
import datetime
nowinIsoFromat = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat("T", "milliseconds") + 'Z'
```